# How to move an aquarium?

Tags: aquarium

When one wants to move an aquarium (say within 10 minutes walking/carrying distance, but answers with hint for long distance (> 1 day travelling in a car) are welcome as well), there probably things to consider regarding the well being of inhabitant and potential damage of the aquarium (be it during the transport or non-visible long term damage (microfissure, breaking silicone joints)). What precautions have to be taken? How long do I have to plan in advance?

Comment: What do you mean by traps? What are you worried about?

Comment: It would be very helpful to us, and give you a better chance of getting a quality answer to your question, if you were to give more specifics. You could add the size of your tank, fresh water vs salt water, do you have live plants or plastic, how far you need to move it (how long the fish might be stressed), the type and quantity of fish to move, etc... The more info we have the better we can give you a tailored answer.

Answer (score 3):

When moving an aquarium (from an old location close to the new one) consider the following:

1. Moving the aquarium means stress for inhabitants and you. So, don't place the aquarium at a worse location than before ((more) direct impact of sunlight which might cause algae growning, less stable or unleveled surface, more noise emission for the room it will stands in).
2. Remove heavy pieces of decoration and all electronical equipment.
3. Only very small aquariums (≤ 60 l) might be carried when almost empty. Carefully evaluate the stress for the inhabitants being contained in an almost empty aquarium for short time and being moved to a temporary location and back. If you have an unused running aquarium at hand, consider using it for some time and moving fish back after days or weeks only to reduce the frequency of moves.

Carry with two persons and lift and base very symetrically in order to minimize the tension on the glass and joints - it's not a piece of furniture. If fish are in the aquarium while carrying, add a cover to prevent them from jumping out.

When moving over a long distance, more things have to be considered and organized; they're not covered by the above listing.

Comment: I think that's a good answer. The only additions I might suggest are saving the water you drain, or at least some of it, so you're adding their water back into the tank. You could also move them to rubber maid tubs for the trip. You'd be able to lock the lid down. The only issue I ever had moving one besides this is I didn't get the cord on the filter wrapped up good. I was going to leave it on. Our grip started to slip and we set it down right on top of the plug. This broke the bottom and made a huge mess.